# What are the good practices for conditional variable assigning?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, variable-assignment

I have a string, that may be empty `("")` or equal to `foo`.

I want to create a variable `my_string` and assign to it the value `foo` of the string, or a value `empty` when the string is empty.

```
var my_string = string == "";
my_string = (string === "") ? "empty" : string;
```

Or

```
(string === "") && var my_string = string;
```

Are these good ways of doing what I am asking?

What are the recommended syntax for this case?

Comment: doesn't matter, as long as you and any other devs can read and understand it

Comment: I found the 1st sample to be the most common one - if this is the definition of good practice for you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var string = "";
var my_string = string || "empty";
```

This expression `string || "empty"` will return the value of the string unless it is falsy (`false`, `null`, `0`, `""`, etc.) or it will return the string `"empty"`.

Or this:

```
var string  = "";
var my_string = string==="" ? string : "empty";
```

I like the first way, but some people like the ternary operation. Both produce the exact same result.

Your example of this:

```
(string === "") && var my_string = string;
```

Is not good coding practice due to the placement of `var`.

Comment: If I was programming in Javascript I would be most likely to use the first one, `my_string = string || "empty";`